# Synchronisation using Dekker's algorithm

Tags: java, synchronization

I want to be able to change the runTrain() method to allow for synchronisation to avoid two trains passing any same time.

public class Peru extends Railway {

```
public Peru() throws SetUpError {
    super("Peru",new Delay(0.1,0.3));
}

/**
 * Run the train on the railway.
 * This method currently does not provide any synchronisation to avoid two 
 * trains being in the pass at the same time.
 */
public void runTrain() throws RailwaySystemError {
    Clock clock = getRailwaySystem().getClock();
    Railway nextRailway = getRailwaySystem().getNextRailway(this);
    while (!clock.timeOut()) {
        choochoo();
        getBasket().putStone(this);
        while (nextRailway.getBasket().hasStone(this)) {
            getBasket().takeStone(this);
            siesta();
            getBasket().putStone(this);
        }
        crossPass();
        getBasket().takeStone(this);
    }
}
```

}

The problem at the minute is my current method isn't allowing synchronisation of letting the two trains pass at the same time. The two trains are Peru and Bolivia.

public class Bolivia extends Railway {

```
public Bolivia() throws SetUpError {
    super("Bolivia",new Delay(0.1,0.3));
}

/**
 * Run the train on the railway.
 * This method currently does not provide any synchronisation to avoid two 
 * trains being in the pass at the same time.
 */
public void runTrain() throws RailwaySystemError {
    Clock clock = getRailwaySystem().getClock();
    Railway nextRailway = getRailwaySystem().getNextRailway(this);
    while (!clock.timeOut()) {
        choochoo();
        getBasket().putStone(this);
        while (nextRailway.getBasket().hasStone(this)) {
            getBasket().takeStone(this);
            siesta();
            getBasket().putStone(this);
        }
        crossPass();
        getBasket().takeStone(this);
    }
}
```

}

Below is the abstract class with all the methods defined from extending the thread.

public abstract class Railway extends Thread {
private String name; // the name of the railway
private static Basket sharedBasket = new Basket("shared basket"); // a shared
// basket for notifications
private Basket basket; // private basket
private RailwaySystem railwaySystem; // the system this railway forms part of
private Delay delay; // the delay used by this railway

```
private Position position; // the position of the train on this railway

public Railway(String name,Delay delay) {
    this.name = name;
    this.delay = delay;
    position = Position.END_PASS; // all trains start just after the
    basket = new Basket(name + "'s basket");
}

/**
 * Register this railway with a railway system
 * @param railwaySystem the railway system this railway must be registered with
 */
public void register(RailwaySystem railwaySystem) {
    this.railwaySystem = railwaySystem;
}

/**
 * Get the railway system this railway is registered with
 * @return the railway system this railway is registered with
 * @throws ProgrammingError if the railway is not registered
 */
public RailwaySystem getRailwaySystem() throws ProgrammingError {
    if (railwaySystem == null) {
        throw new ProgrammingError(name + " is not registered with a railway 
        system");
    }
    return railwaySystem;
}

/**
 * Get this railway's name
 * @return this railway's name
 */
public String name() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * Get this railway's private basket.
 * @return this railway's private basket
 */
public Basket getBasket() {
    return basket;
}

/**
 * Get the shared basket.
 * @return the basket shared between all railways.
 */
public static Basket getSharedBasket() {
    return sharedBasket;
}

/**
 * Use delay to generate a delay for this railway
 */
public void delay() {
    delay.delay();
}

// Fields keeping track of trains in the pass
private static int trainsInPass = 0; // how many trains are in the pass

/**
 * Defines parts of the railway system. These are specified as:
 * <ul>
 *     <li> START_PASS: just before entering the shared pass.</li>
 *     <li> IN_PASS: in the shared pass.</li>
 *     <li> END_PASS: at the end of the shared pass.</li>
 * </ul>
 * Trains start at the end of the pass, and must thereafter cycle through 
 * positions START_PASS, IN_PASS, END_PASS.
 */
public static enum Position {
    START_PASS, IN_PASS, END_PASS;
    
    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
        case START_PASS: return "at the start of the pass";
        case IN_PASS: return "in the pass";
        case END_PASS: return "at the end of the pass";
        default: return "at an undefined position on the railway (ERROR)";
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Enter the pass.
 * This method does <i>not</i> check if it is safe to enter the pass. It is 
 * merely for
 * administration of the information about trains in the pass.
 * @throws ProgrammingError if this railway thinks it already has a train in 
 * the pass.
 */
private synchronized void enterPass() throws ProgrammingError {
    railwaySystem.trace(name + ": entering pass");
    if (position != Position.START_PASS) {
        throw new ProgrammingError(name + " cannot enter the pass, it is not " 
        + Position.START_PASS + ", it is " + position + ".");
    }
    position = Position.IN_PASS;
    trainsInPass++;
}

/**
 * Leave the pass.
 * This method is merely for administration of the information about trains in 
 * the pass.
 * @throws ProgrammingError if this railway thinks it does not have a train in 
 * the pass,
 *                          or if there is no record of any trains in the pass.
 */
private synchronized void leavePass() throws ProgrammingError {
    if (position != Position.IN_PASS) {
        throw new ProgrammingError(name + " cannot leave the pass, it is not " 
        + Position.IN_PASS + ", it is " + position + ".");
    }
    if (trainsInPass == 0) {
        throw new ProgrammingError("There is no train to leave the pass (even 
        though " + name + " thinks it is in the pass.");
    }
    position = Position.END_PASS;
    trainsInPass--;
    railwaySystem.trace(name + ": leaving pass");
}

/**
 * Travel round the safe part of the railway (outside the pass).
 * @throws ProgrammingError if the train is not currently at the end of the 
 * pass (and therefore at the start of the
 *         safe part of the railway).
 */
public void choochoo() throws ProgrammingError {
    if (position != Position.END_PASS) {
        throw new ProgrammingError(name + " cannot traverse safe section, it is 
        not " + Position.END_PASS + ", it is " + position + ".");
    }
    railwaySystem.trace (name + ": choo-choo");
    delay();
    position = Position.START_PASS;
}

/**
 * Have a siesta.
 */
public void siesta() {
    railwaySystem.trace(name + ": zzzzz");
    delay();
}

/**
 * Cross the pass.
 * @throws SafetyViolationError if there is/are already train(s) on the pass.
 */
public void crossPass() throws RailwaySystemError {
    enterPass();
    if (trainsInPass > 1) {
        throw new SafetyViolationError("There are now " + trainsInPass + " 
        trains in the pass!");
    }
    railwaySystem.trace(name + ": crossing pass");
    delay();
    leavePass();
}

// Error flag must be shared so that we can stop all railways if something goes 
// wrong    

private static boolean errorFlag = false;
protected static String errorMessage = "";

/**
 * Run the railway.
 */
public void run() {
    setErrorFlag(false);
    try {
        runTrain();
    } catch (RailwaySystemError error) {
        setErrorFlag(true);
        errorMessage = error.getMessage();
        System.out.println("!!! Something went wrong with the railway.\n\t" + 
        errorMessage);
    }
    if (errorOccurred()) {
        System.out.println("!!! " + name() + " shut down because of an 
        error.\n\t" + errorMessage);
    } else {
        System.out.println(name() + " shut down because time limit was 
        reached.");
    }
}

/**
 * Each railway should independently define how the trains are to be run, using 
 * the basket(s).
 * to maintain safety on the pass.
 * @throws RailwaySystemError if a safety violation occurs while the railway is 
 * being run.
 */
public abstract void runTrain() throws RailwaySystemError, RailwaySystemError;

/**
 * Set the shared error flag (if an error occurs).
 * @param errorFlag is true iff an error has occured.
 */
public static void setErrorFlag(boolean errorFlag) {
    Railway.errorFlag = errorFlag;
}

/**
 * Check the current error status.
 * @return true iff an error is currently active.
 */
public static boolean errorOccurred() {
    return errorFlag;
}
```

}

Finally I have got the class which holds the main method.

public class RailwaySystem {

```
private Clock clock = null; // the clock used to time railways - must be initialised for 
// each run
private List<Railway> railways;

public RailwaySystem(List<Railway> railways,Clock clock) {
    this.clock = clock;
    this.railways = railways;
    clock.register(this);
    for (Railway railway: railways) {
        railway.register(this);
    }
}

/**
 * Start the railway system
 */
private void start() {
    clock.start();
    for (Railway railway: railways) {
        railway.start();
    }
}

/**
 * Wait for the system to stop
 */
private void stop() throws RailwaySystemError {
    try {
        clock.join();
        for (Railway railway: railways) {
            railway.join();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException interrupt) {
        throw new RailwaySystemError("The railway system was interrupted: " + 
        interrupt.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Given a railway, get the next one in the system's list
 * @param railway the given railway
 * @return the next railway in the list 
 * @throws ProgrammingError if railway is neither peru not bolivia
 */
public Railway getNextRailway(Railway railway) throws ProgrammingError {
    int index = railways.indexOf(railway);
    if (index == -1) { // railway is not in the list
        throw new ProgrammingError(railway.name() + " is not registered with this system");
    }
    return railways.get((index+1) % railways.size());
}

/**
 * Get this system's clock
 * @return the system's clock
 * @throws SetUpError if the clock is not initialised
 */
public Clock getClock() throws SetUpError {
    if (clock == null) {
        throw new SetUpError("Clock has not been intialised");
    }
    return clock;
}

/**
 * Provide a facility for switching tracing on/off.
 **/
private boolean tracingOn = false;

/**
 * Switch tracing on.
 **/
public void traceOn() {
    tracingOn = true;
}

/**
 * Switch tracing off.
 **/
public void traceOff() {
    tracingOn = false;
}

/**
 * Trace, if tracing is on
 * @param trace the trace to be output
 */
public synchronized void trace(String trace) {
    if (tracingOn) {
        System.out.println(trace);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RailwaySystemError {
    List<Railway> railways = new ArrayList<Railway>();
    railways.add(new Peru());
    railways.add(new Bolivia());
    Clock clock = new Clock(1.0,20); // 20 ticks of 1 second
    RailwaySystem system = new RailwaySystem(railways,clock);
    system.traceOn();
    system.start();
    system.stop();
}
```

}

I need to allow for synchronisation in my runTrain() method, is the problem I am currently having. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The code you're working off of is buggy. That's... not a good sign, your prof / the book doesn't understand threading and yet they are trying to teach you.

```
public void traceOff() {
    tracingOn = false;
}
```

```
public synchronized void trace(String trace) {
    if (tracingOn) {
        System.out.println(trace);
    }
}
```

Every thread has an evil coin. Any time any thread accesses any variable (for read or write), that thread flips this coin. Heads, and it will use its own local copy. Even though there is only one field, every thread has a cached copy of it, and on heads, the thread updates/looks at only its local copy. Tails, and it uses/updates the actual field and not the copy.

The coin is evil: It is not a 'fair' coin, and it may well flip tails every single time today, when you're writing it and running your tests. And then when the important customer comes in and you demo your app, the coin flips heads all the time. Because Murphy just doesn't like you.

The solution is to either stop the VM from flipping the coin, or to ensure your code does not care about the result.

The one and only way to ensure the VM doesn't flip it, is to establish a so-called 'comes before/comes after' (CBCA) relationship between the line that sets the field, and the line that reads the field.

In other words, the above pair of actions (`traceOff` and `trace`) **do not work as intended** and result in flips of that evil coin, unless a CBCA relationship is set up such that the `tracingOn = false` call 'comes before' the `if (tracingOn)` call. This means: Given the scenario where thread A sets tracing to on, and 3 hours later, thread B calls `trace`, the JVM is allowed to act as if `tracing` is on, and that'd be a legal VM. It can also act as if `tracing` is off, and that'd also be legal: The JMM intentionally makes no guarantees either way. Obviously that is a buggy app. Clearly the point should be that tracing is definitely always on here. Unfortunately, that requires a CBCA relationship and this code does not establish this. So, how to make that happen?

`synchronized` is one way to do so, but it is not done properly here. Whenever code exits a `synchronized (x)` block, then when other code later enters a `synchronized (x)` block (and due to synchronized, these events cannot possibly occur simultaneously), all code executed by thread 1 has 'come before' code from thread 2.

This is not happening here: the `traceOff` method isn't `synchronized` at all, thus no CBCA relationship exists, thus **this code is broken**.

---

> `private static Basket sharedBasket = new Basket("shared basket");`

This should definitely be `final`.

> The problem at the minute is my current method isn't allowing synchronisation of letting the two trains pass at the same time.

That doesn't seem right. Your code does *try* to address this; that's surely what all the stuff about putting stones in a basket is about:

> ```
> getBasket().putStone(this);
> while (nextRailway.getBasket().hasStone(this)) {
>   getBasket().takeStone(this);
>   siesta();
>   getBasket().putStone(this);
>  }
> ```

This code makes no sense - a stone in the basket is a sign that there is another train in the pass, so when there is a stone there, you wait, but you take the stone! That'd mean if a third train shows up, kaboom. Don't touch the stone. Leave it be.

I assume the code for that basket is provided (not written by you), and is thread-safe, but as we have established that your prof / this book doesn't seem to know how to write threadsafe code, that is an assumption that, as wikipedians would say, gets a *[citation needed]*. Assuming the basket code is proper and threadsafe, then, you have all the tools you need, but you're not using them in the right way.

The idea is no doubt that, to cross the pass, you must put a stone in the basket but only if there isn't a stone there yet, then cross the pass, then take the stone out to indicate you're done with your trip. If you can't put a stone in the basket (because there is already a stone inside), then wait for a while and try again later. Don't enter the pass until you managed to successfully put a stone in the empty basket.

There are 2 important realizations here:

1. The task of 'check if stone is in basket' and 'put stone in basket' are intertwined: You can't do them sequentially; what if both trains both check the basket, both see it is empty, and then both put a stone in, and then both enter the pass, and then both crash and die a horrible fiery death? The concept of 'put a stone in, but only if there is no stone yet, and report if it succeeded' is one single operation that cannot be split up - this is called an **atomic** operation.
2. No matter what or how, whatever train put a stone in the basket needs to ensure it removes the stone when done, no matter how the train exits the pass.

The basket needs to support it, and it is not clear if it does. Does the `putStone` method fail if there is already a stone in? If it does, how does it fail? Does it return a boolean `false`, or does it throw something?

If it doesn't fail (you can put stones in a basket even if it already has a stone in), the method is almost completely useless - you'd need to `synchronize` on something to get to your atomicity requirement.

if it does fail, then use that. Your algorithm needs to change to something like this:

```
while (true) { // keep trying until we succeed.
    boolean actuallyPlacedStone = basket.putStoneIfBasketEmpty(this);
    if (!actuallyPlacedStone) {
       // the basket is filled, we can't go.
       siesta(); // sleep a while, and ...
       continue; // start from the top
    }

    // if we got here, we placed the stone!
    try {
        crossThePass();
    } finally {
        // no matter how we get out of that pass, be it on rails
        // or by tumbling down the mountain in a horrible accident...
        // the pass is now clear, so, take the stone with you.
        basket.takeStone(this);
    }
    break; // we're through, no need to repeat this process.
}
```

If basket makes no thread guarantees whatsoever, I guess we can use it as a lock. *ALL* interactions with that basket **must** now be in a synchronized block, both to ensure no 2 threads act on the basket simultaneously, as well as to establish CBCA all around and avoid the evil coin from ruining our day. I'd make helper methods:

```
public boolean placeStoneIfEmpty(Basket b) {
    synchronized (b) {
        if (b.hasStone()) return false;
        b.putStone(this);
        return true;
    }
}

public void removeStone(Basket b) {
    synchronized (b) {
        b.removeStone(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response. The synchronisation needs to happen to avoid two trains entering the pass. That was my mistake, sorry.

Comment: `a so-called 'comes before/comes after' (CBCA) relationship` The Java language specification does not call it this.  It uses *happens-before.*  (And for the action which causes this it's *synchronizes-with.*)  Your terminology is novel to me, I've never heard anyone use it in 15 years of Java programming.  ("Evil coin" is a great analogy though.)

Comment: Yes, I got that - this answer covers all details you need: [1] that the code you're working off of is suspect to say the least, [2] what you need to do assuming Basket has what you need (specifically, an atomic 'put in basket but only if it is empty'), and [3] what you need to do if basket doesn't have that. With the proper ops on that basket, you can trivially ensure that no train enters the pass if another is already in there.

Comment: I also need the algorithm to end as well at some point!! The code below is what needs to be included also! Clock clock = getRailwaySystem().getClock();
    Railway nextRailway = getRailwaySystem().getNextRailway(this);